# How does JQuery Bootstrap trigger *.data-api events

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to understand some of the innards of jQuery Bootstrap.  I'm trying to figure out how/where the js-events in Bootstrap 3.0+ are fired.  For example, I see in bootstrap button.js you have the on click events defined like:

```
 $(document)
  .on('click.bs.button.data-api',
```

So where is this event triggered in the Bootstrap core?  I'm searching, and can't find anything like this.

Thanks for your help.

Karl..

Comment: Not sure where it's actually coded, but if you're asking how it's fired it tells you right there, when the user clicks on a class that has bs, button and data-api together

Comment: I'm unclear about what you're asking, but the event is triggered as it says on click of the document. And the part after "click" is the [namespace](https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/), for easier removal. See [CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/namespaced-events-jquery/) for more info.

Comment: My question is: where is this event triggered in the Bootstrap core?

Answer (score 0):

The event name is actually "click". What comes after the first "." is the namespace. So event "click.bs.button.data-api" is never triggered, but "click" is triggered (I think by your browser). Event namespaces are great if you want to register and then unregister specific event handlers. If you do .on("EVENT_NAME.NAMESPACE") and then .off("EVENT_NAME"), you'll see that your event handler is not actually unregistered. You have to do .off("EVENT_NAME.NAMESPACE").

So, in conclusion, if you listen for "EVENT_NAME.NAMESPACE", your function will actually be triggered by any "EVENT_NAME" event.